# did we eat it up

Tags: inversion

*Back in December 2015, Netflix blessed us with the epic docuseries “Making a Murderer,” and man, **did we eat it up**.*

Source: http://elitedaily.com/news/making-a-murderer-lawyer-details/1795570/

Why is "did we eat it up" used instead of "we did eat it up". Is this some sort of inversion?

Comment: It's quite a popular inversion. usually comes after words like "man", "dude", "boy", "wow" ("Boy! am I glad to see you!").

Comment: @MorganFR isn't it called *exclamative inversion* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclamatory inversion. This sort of inversion could be called by several names.
The inversion gets the attention of the reader, or, listener [H.W. Fowler](http://www.bartleby.com/116/303.html)